# Ошибка при загрузке плагина maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: java, maven

При попытке Maven загрузить плагин surefire-plugin возникает ошибка:

--- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) @ OnlineBroker ---
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-provider-api/1.0-beta-6/wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-6.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-compat/3.0/maven-compat-3.0.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-toolchain/3.0-alpha-2/maven-toolchain-3.0-alpha-2.jar

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) on project OnlineBroker: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:3.0-alpha-2, org.apache.maven:maven-compat:jar:3.0, org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:3.0-alpha-2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

Версия Maven: 3.6.0

Файл pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>qa</groupId>
<artifactId>OnlineBroker</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.8.0</version>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
         </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/TestSuite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

При этом если использовать встроенную в NetBeans версию Maven 3.0.5 и версию Maven Surefire Plugin 2.22.1, то при сборке ошибка не возникает.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена настройкой подключения maven по http.

Comment: можешь прописать путь до настройки maven это settings.xml ?